# Django query date range by url

Tags: django

I have a model with an attribute tracking things by date added, and I want to be able to query for objects added after a certain date. There is a `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter` that looks useful, but I don't see any guidance on how to format my URLs to make use of it. How can I query for objects by a range of dates?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any native support for date-url mapping in Django, but it can be done with some effort.
For example, you may write your url mapping as follows in `urls.py`

```
url(r'^date-filter/(?P<from-date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/(?P<to-date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.date_filter, name='date_filter'),
```

And your views might look like this:

```
import dateutil.parser
def date_filter(request,from_date,to_date):
    #You can then convert to_date and from_date to date-time objects
    #Like this
    to_date_object = parser.parse(to_date)
    from_date_object = parser.parse(from_date)
```

Once you have the date-time objects, you can fire filter queries in any way you like.